# Building a custom indirect actuator, any thoughts?

Tags: motors, design, gears, robotics, actuator

**I’m trying to create a custom indirect actuator, that is controlled by a microcontroller, for a custom robotics project.**

**I have selected motor and gears (according to F*d = W = T*2*pi) so that the actuator should be able to push with around 46N of force** (10N over what I require to make up for any losses or forces, such as friction, efficiencies of gears, etc).

**I want to be able to tell the instantaneous stroke of the actuator and the force it is exerting at any time.**

**But the solution I'm hoping for should be cheap and easy to implement,** as we are hoping to send our finished robotics design into mass production.

**My initial approach:** was to use a rudimentary potentiometer/voltage divider. Connecting the wiper to the microcontroller will allow me to see the position of the wiper with respect to the conductive strip. Could I use this potentiometer to also calculate dynamic force?

If I constantly poll the wiper while the actuator is active, I could get two position values and the time between them. This would give me an instantaneous velocity value. Doing the same thing again would give me a second value which I could use to find the instantaneous acceleration.

**The problem with this is the mass.** I have read that actuators have an “effective mass/weight” – a value that is usually incorporated somehow in the datasheet. However, my actuator would be a custom design therefore there is no datasheet accessible for this.

**Can anyone please help me figure out the effective mass/weight of my actuator? Or if you have any other approach please do let me know.**

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful, if you added a sketch and some details.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply. I would be happy to add a drawing or some more information about this. Can you kindly specify what I should expand on?